# Spring MVC web app cannot find org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Im trying to setup a Spring MVC web app using Hibernate ORM. Im using JBOSS AS.

There is a problem when Im trying to define a datasource bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I run the app and access it via browser, it throws an exception -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class     [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext     resource [/WEB-INF/servletCtx.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource from [Module "deployment.untitled1.war:main" from Service     Module Loader]
```

I've read somewhere that this datasource approach is old and deprecated. Is it true? What else would you suggest?

Thanks for hints and help.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` means the required JAR file that contains `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` is not available in classpath, just add it to fix the issue.

Instead of configuring it as a data-source use JNDI connection.